# What does it mean for a geodesic to be orthogonal to a submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, orthogonality, geodesic, semi-riemannian-geometry

I mean obviously a geodesic $c:I \rightarrow M$ is orthogonal to some tangent vector $v\in T_pM$, if $g(v, c^{'}(0))=0$ right (if $c(0)=p$) but if I have a submanifold $S \subset M$, what does it mean, if $c$ is orthogonal to $S$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geodesic $c$ is normal to $S$ if whenever $c(t)\in S$, we have $c'(t)\in T_{c(t)}S^\perp$.

Comment: But how is $T_{c(t)}S^{\perp}$ defined? Isn't $c(t)$ supposed to be in $S^{\perp}$ then?

Comment: $c(t)$ is a point in the manifold $M$. $T_{c(t)}M$ is a vector space, which has $T_{c(t)}S$ as a subspace. The subspace $T_{c(t)}S$ has an orthogonal complement $T_{c(t)}S^\perp$ in $T_{c(t)}M$. This is just linear algebra.

Comment: ohh I see, I thought you meant $T_{c(t)}(S^{\perp})$ but you meant $(T_{c(t)}S)^{\perp}$ right?

Comment: Since $S^\perp$ by itself is not even defined in general, $T_{c(t)}S^\perp$ cannot mean anything other than $(T_{c(t)}S)^\perp$ here.

Comment: Ok, yes you're right, thanks!